# Python Script to Convert list to JSON format

Tags: python, json

Good Day,
I am new to python. I am trying to write a program that takes in a excel document containing list of books and authors, and selecting only the authors column and breaking it into first name and last name and then writing it to a json file.
Currently I have successfully able to complete data loading, extraction and splitting. But i have no clue or idea on how to save it as json.
The authors list is around 100+
Following is the code I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd

def unique(list1): 
    unique_list = [] 

    # traverse for all elements 
    for x in list1: 
        # check if exists in unique_list or not 
        if x not in unique_list: 
            unique_list.append(x) 

    return unique_list

tbr = pd.read_excel('TBR.xlsx')
idx_of_column = 3-1
authors =  tbr.iloc[:,idx_of_column]
# print(authors)
authors_list = authors.values.tolist()
cleaned_author_List = [x for x in authors_list if str(x) != 'nan']

unique_cleaned_author_list = unique(cleaned_author_List)

for fullname in unique_cleaned_author_list:
    firstname = fullname.strip().split(' ')[0]
    lastname = ' '.join((fullname + ' ').split(' ')[1:]).strip()
    print('FirstName: ',firstname)
    print('Lastname: ',lastname)
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: have you looked at the standard json module https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json.dumps()` to serialize your list to a JSON string, and write it to a file:

```
import json

...

names = []
for fullname in unique_cleaned_author_list:
    firstname = fullname.strip().split(' ')[0]
    lastname = ' '.join((fullname + ' ').split(' ')[1:]).strip()

    names.append({
        'first_name': firstname,
        'last_name': lastname,
    })

with open('names.json', 'w') as f:
   print(json.dumps(names), file=f)
```